# Sprite leaves a tail behind it in PlayMode

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering

Recently I downloaded *Universal RP* and changed Render Pipeline Settings:

[image]

After this, all of my sprites in a scene started going insane in *PlayMode*:

[image]

Could you help, how such a type of bug is called? I just can't find any info about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your camera has the clear flags of "Nothing". Maybe change it to "depth" or "color".
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-clearFlags.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the clear flag because I use Universal Renderer Pipeline :(

Comment: Oh, I've tried to change the clear flags in code and it has worked out! Thank you :)

Comment: Anytime. If you change the "Inspector" tab to "Debug mode", you can also see the "Clear flags" field in the inspector - with the Universal Render Pipeline.